# Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null bootstrap collapse

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am writing php code for bootstrap collapse and taking error Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null. I spend really a lot of time to this simple problem. If I put without php that is working really norm without error
Error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null
at a.t._getParent (collapse.js:300)
at new a (collapse.js:88)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (collapse.js:345)
at Function.each (jquery.js:368)
at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:157)
at jQuery.fn.init.a._jQueryInterface [as collapse] (collapse.js:331)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (collapse.js:378)
at Function.each (jquery.js:368)
at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:157)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (collapse.js:374)
```

That is my php code

```
<div id="info-content" class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
                  <?
                    $faqs = get_field('faqs');
                    foreach ($faqs as $key => $value):
                  ?>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne<?=$key;?>">
                      <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne<?=$key;?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne<?=$key;?>">
                          <?=$value['question'];?>
                        </button>
                      </h5>
                      <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne<?=$key;?>" class="collapse <?if($key==0):?>show<?endif;?>" aria-labelledby="headingOne<?=$key;?>" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <?=$value['answer'];?>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <?endforeach;?>
                </div>
```

Comment: More than likely you are providing the wrong css selector for your `data-parent`,  `data-target`, or any other attributes which use a selector value. If those values are not correct using them with `querySelectorAll` could lead to a null return value and if the library doesn't do proper check cause an error. Make sure they are correct

Comment: I checked however but I am not found where

Answer (score 46):

This is due to a change in Bootstrap 4.1.1 or 2 to 4.1.3.

Same error happens when you use `data-parent="selector"` while it should be `data-parent="#selectorId"` or `data-parent=".selectorClassName"`.

This error used to void silently but now it displays this console error.

Comment: I had a similar issue when migrating from Bootstrap v4.0 to v4.3. Apparently, collapsables in v4 does not need data-parent but in v4.3 they do.

Comment: Removing `data-parent="#accordion` fixed it for me.

Comment: Thank you, removing data-parent="#accordion" also did it for me.

Answer (score 8):

This problem happened to me with the usage of bootstrap 4.1.3, I was not noticing it before.

For me, the problem is that the data-parent attribute of the collapse element held a reference to a non-existing element.

Once I changed it to a valid element, the problem disappeared.

Comment: Yeah, this was essentially my problem. I'd put the correct element ID in the `data-parent` attribute, but missed the fact that I had to prefix it with a # to make it a valid jQuery selector. I.e. it's `data-parent="#accordionExample"`, not `data-parent="accordionExample"`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem too. For me it was due to missing `id` in the main navbar container. See the `id` the `ul` below,

```
<ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion" id="accordionSidebar">
   <!-- Nav Item - Dashboard -->
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseUtilities" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseUtilities">
      <i class="fas fa-fw fa-wrench"></i>
      <span>Utilities</span>
    </a>
    <div id="collapseUtilities" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingUtilities" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
      <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
        <h6 class="collapse-header">Custom Utilities:</h6>
        <a class="collapse-item" href="utilities-color.html">Colors</a>
        <a class="collapse-item" href="utilities-border.html">Borders</a>
        <a class="collapse-item" href="utilities-animation.html">Animations</a>
        <a class="collapse-item" href="utilities-other.html">Other</a>
      </div>
    </div>
 </li>     
</ul>
```

Hope this helps someone.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that if you are doing custom inclusion of the bootstrap javascript plugins separately, that you include util.js before collapse.js.

That's what did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to update the popper.js!

You can do it from here: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/popper.js/2.5.3

Answer (score 0):

Besides collapse.js, you need to load bootsrap util.js too

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because your ul id="accordionSidebar" is the same as your a data-parent="#accordionExample".

Try:

```
<div id="info-content" class="accordion" id="#accordionExample">
  <?
  $faqs = get_field('faqs');
  foreach ($faqs as $key => $value):
  ?>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne<?=$key;?>">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne<?=$key;?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne<?=$key;?>">
        <?=$value['question'];?>
        </button>
      </h5>
      <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne<?=$key;?>" class="collapse <?if($key==0):?>show<?endif;?>" aria-labelledby="headingOne<?=$key;?>" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        <?=$value['answer'];?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?endforeach;?>
</div>
```